# How to specify multiple values in list key attribute of select tag in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, html-select

Select tag in jsp is containing list of Plan objects

Here is a Plan class

```
public class Plan {

    private String packageId;
    private String packageName;
    private String price;

    public String getPackageId() {
        return packageId;
    }
    public void setPackageId(String packageId) {
        this.packageId = packageId;
    }
    public String getPackageName() {
        return packageName;
    }
    public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
        this.packageName = packageName;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}

<s:select theme="simple" list="%{#request.packageList}" listKey="packageId" 
    listValue="packageName" headerKey="0" headerValue="--Select--"
    name="packageID" class="dropdowm" id="packageID" />
```

Now i want `listkey to have multiple values separated by comma like(packageId,price)`

**How can i achieve this ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply specify it in the key attribute:

```xml
<s:select theme = "simple" 
           list = "%{#request.packageList}" 
        listKey = "packageId + ',' + price" 
      listValue = "packageName" 
      headerKey = "0" 
    headerValue = "--Select--"
           name = "myNewCustomKey" 
       cssClass = "dropdowm" 
             id = "packageID" />
```

And (if you are *not* using a recent version) use `cssClass` instead of `class` in Struts Tags.